# Entity Framework 4 Context?

Tags: model-view-controller, entity-framework-4, repository-pattern, unit-of-work, objectcontext

I was just looking for some feedback on what others are doing to manage their context when using EF4. I am creating an MVC app, using (I think :)) the Unit of Work, Service Layer, Repository, EF4 w/POCO technique.

My Controllers utilize services which take a UOW, which then utilize repositories to get POCO's from the EF.

Is this implemented correctly?

Have a look below, and any feedback is appreciated!!

**Controller**

```
Public Class MyController
    Function ListCustomers() As ActionResult
        Dim _UOW = New UnitOfWork
        Dim _Service = New CustomerService(_UOW)
        Dim _Model = New CustomersViewModel
        _Model.Customers = _Service.GetCustomers
        _UOW.Dispose()

        Return View(_Model)
    End Function
End Class
```

**Unit of Work**

```
Public Interface IUnitOfWork
    Property Context As GTGContext
    Sub Committ()

End Interface

Public Class UnitOfWork
    Implements IDisposable, IUnitOfWork

    Public Property Context As Domain.GTGContext Implements IUnitOfWork.Context

    Public Sub New()
        _Context = New GTGContext

    End Sub

    Public Sub Committ() Implements IUnitOfWork.Committ
        _Context.SaveChanges()

    End Sub

#Region "IDisposable Support"

    Private _IsDisposed As Boolean

    Protected Overridable Sub Dispose(ByVal Disposing As Boolean)
        If (Not _IsDisposed) Then
            If (Disposing) Then
                If (_Context IsNot Nothing) Then
                    _Context.Dispose()
                End If
            End If

            'TODO: Free unmanaged resources (unmanaged objects) and override Finalize() below.
        End If

        _IsDisposed = True

    End Sub

    'TODO: Override Finalize() only if Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean) above has code to free unmanaged resources.
    'Protected Overrides Sub Finalize()
    '    Dispose(False)
    '    MyBase.Finalize()
    'End Sub

    Public Sub Dispose() Implements IDisposable.Dispose
        Dispose(True)
        GC.SuppressFinalize(Me)

    End Sub

#End Region

End Class
```

**Service**

```
Public Class CustomerService
    Private _UOW As IUnitOfWork
    Private _Repo As Repository(Of Customer)

    Public Sub New(UOW As IUnitOfWork)
        _UOW = UOW
        _Repo = New Repository(Of Customer)(_UOW)
    End Sub

    Public Function GetCustoemrs() As IQueryable(Of Customer)
        ' Any Business Logic Here
        Return _Repo.GetCustomers()
    End Function

End Class
```

**Repository**

```
Imports System.Data.Objects

Namespace Repositories
    Public Interface IRepository(Of T As Class)
        ReadOnly Property ObjectSet As IObjectSet(Of T)
        ReadOnly Property UnitOfWork As IUnitOfWork
        Function Query(ByVal Expression As Expressions.Expression(Of Func(Of T, Boolean))) As IQueryable(Of T)
        Function GetFirst(ByVal Expression As Expressions.Expression(Of Func(Of T, Boolean))) As T
        Function GetSingle(ByVal Expression As Expressions.Expression(Of Func(Of T, Boolean))) As T
        Sub Add(ByVal Entity As T)
        Sub Attach(ByVal Entity As T)
        Sub Delete(ByVal Entity As T)
        Sub SaveChanges()

    End Interface

    Public Class Repository(Of T As Class)
        Implements IRepository(Of T)

#Region "Private Members/Properties"

        Private _ObjectSet As IObjectSet(Of T)
        Private ReadOnly Property ObjectSet As System.Data.Objects.IObjectSet(Of T) Implements IRepository(Of T).ObjectSet
            Get
                If (_ObjectSet Is Nothing) Then
                    _ObjectSet = UnitOfWork.Context.CreateObjectSet(Of T)()
                End If
                Return _ObjectSet
            End Get
        End Property

        Private _UnitOfWork As IUnitOfWork
        Private ReadOnly Property UnitOfWork As IUnitOfWork Implements IRepository(Of T).UnitOfWork
            Get
                Return _UnitOfWork
            End Get
        End Property

#End Region

#Region "Constructor(s)"

        Public Sub New(ByVal UnitOfWork As IUnitOfWork)
            If (UnitOfWork Is Nothing) Then
                Throw New ArgumentNullException("UnitOfWork")
            End If
            _UnitOfWork = UnitOfWork

        End Sub

#End Region

#Region "IRepository(Of T)"

        Public Sub Add(ByVal Entity As T) Implements IRepository(Of T).Add
            ObjectSet.AddObject(Entity)

        End Sub

        Public Sub Attach(ByVal Entity As T) Implements IRepository(Of T).Attach
            ObjectSet.Attach(Entity)
            UnitOfWork.Context.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(Entity, EntityState.Modified)

        End Sub

        Public Sub Delete(ByVal Entity As T) Implements IRepository(Of T).Delete
            ObjectSet.DeleteObject(Entity)

        End Sub

        Public Function GetFirst(ByVal Expression As System.Linq.Expressions.Expression(Of System.Func(Of T, Boolean))) As T Implements IRepository(Of T).GetFirst
            Return ObjectSet.FirstOrDefault(Expression)

        End Function

        Public Function GetSingle(ByVal Expression As System.Linq.Expressions.Expression(Of System.Func(Of T, Boolean))) As T Implements IRepository(Of T).GetSingle
            Return ObjectSet.SingleOrDefault(Expression)

        End Function

        Public Function Query(ByVal Expression As System.Linq.Expressions.Expression(Of System.Func(Of T, Boolean))) As System.Linq.IQueryable(Of T) Implements IRepository(Of T).Query
            Return ObjectSet.Where(Expression)

        End Function

        Public Sub SaveChanges() Implements IRepository(Of T).SaveChanges
            UnitOfWork.Committ()

        End Sub

#End Region

    End Class
End Namespace
```

Comment: from your summary this sounds about right, I'm using similar - besides the typo in your `Committ()` method ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Let me tell you, I agonised over what approach to take for a long time, mostly on StackOverflow :)

I settled on an implementation of this fine article on managing the object context (take note of the ammended version allowing for multiple contexts).

http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/ado_net/Managing-Entity-Framework-ObjectContext-lifespan-and-scope-in-n-layered-ASP-NET-applications.aspx

Then I implemented facades like:

```
public class MyEntityFacade : FacadeBase<MyEntities, MyEntity>
{
    public object GetAll()
    {
        return this.ObjectContext.MyEntities.ToList();
    }

    public bool HasChild(int parentId)
    {
        return this.ObjectContext.MyEntityChild.Any(c => c.parentId == parentId);
    }
}
```

Sure, it's old but boy oh boy, it works!

See, the thing with all that service layer / unit of work / repository stuff is you end up having to write a hell of a lot of code just to support it (and surely EF4 was supposed to reduce code bloat!). Every time you add a new entity, guess what? Even more tedious code bloat.

With the method above, I have all the facade / unit of work support code stuffed into a reusable class library and all I have to do is write my facade code, which is ONLY concerned with code that actually does something - and it works with multiple contexts.

Works for me... ooh and don't lambast me on the use of the word 'facade'. I never really went to school ;)

Thanks,
Richard

P.s. Have a great weekend!